# c++ and winforms - how to set up the program?

Tags: c++, winforms

Its my first c++ program and I am trying to start with the right foot. I have set up C++CLR Winforms in visual studio 2017 and created a new project.

Inside this Project I have my Form1 with a Label. I am able to edit this label from code from inside my form1.cpp.

Now, I would like to have my program in the background and have the form as a interface to the user, thus, I would like to avoid putting all the relevant code inside the form. For example, If i code a simple counter, that displays the value, I do not want to have the counter inside my cpp file. I would like to have it in my main(), and use the form just do display the value.

now, there are a few questions raising with this:

- is the main() the one i find in 'sourcefiles/CppCLR_WinformsProject.cpp/main()'?
- is it even a good idea to put things into the main() or should it stay empty and would I have to put my code in separate classes?
- how can I access the label1 on form1 from the main or any other given class?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: "would I have to put my code in separate classes?" If you do object oriented programming, you put your code into separate classes according the SOLID principles.

Comment: "how can I access the label1 on form1 from the main or any other given class?" - you don't access it directly, because it would behave like a global variable then. Use a UI pattern like MVC, MVP or MVVM instead.